# How to find a word after a specific word?

Tags: excel, formula

I need to find the one word after the specific word
If you guys have any idea in the Formula.

Eg: I have in column D2

P/N:101174 JOYSTICK, 2 AXIS, DEUTSCH

So the word after P/N: is `101174` *//this is the answer that i want*

I am using the formula :

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID($D2,SEARCH("P/N",D2)+LEN("P/N")+1,LEN(D2)))," ",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(D:D)*100))
```

the outcome will be :

```
101174 JOYSTICK, 2 AXIS,
```

And what the formula means? because i also google it.
Especially the 100 at the last sentence is what for ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand exactly what it is you're aiming to do. Taking a best guess approach, I think this does what you're aiming for:

```
=MID(D2,SEARCH("P/N:",D2)+4,SEARCH(" ",D2,SEARCH("P/N:",D2)+4)-SEARCH("P/N:",D2)-4)
```

What is does:
a) `MID` gets characters from a string, starting at a given point and for a given number of chars
b) `SEARCH("P/N:",D2)+4` provides the starting point by finding where `P/N:` starts then adding its own length `4` to get the next char's starting point
c) `SEARCH(" ",D2,SEARCH("P/N:",D2)+4)` finds the position of the first space after the location of `"P/N:"` (using the same logic as b)
d) `-SEARCH("P/N:",D2)-4` deducts the position of where we started (to get the word length)

In all cases, `4` is the length of the reference/starting 'word'.

The above could be simplified greatly if `P/N:` (or whatever the first word is) was always at the left.
But that seems at odds with the OP (which implies there could be preceding characters).

If it is the case that the reference/starting 'word' is always at the left, then you can replace searching for that with the following (Where `5` is the length of the leading 'word' + 1 and `4` is the length of the leading 'word'):

```
=MID(D2,5,SEARCH(" ",D2,4)-5)
```

Additional info: `SEARCH` does case in-sensitive search. Use `FIND` if you want the search to be case-sensitive.

Comment: So the word after P/N: is ``` 101174 ``` _//this is the answer that i want_

Comment: Confused here. Both options I've presented do just that (with differences as explained). Are you (in effect) saying 'these work'?

Comment: I'm confused also as my formula worked for extracting the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=TRIM(MID(D10,LEN(LEFT(D10, SEARCH("P/N:",D10,1)+4)),SEARCH(" ",D10,1)-4))`

Comment: So the word after P/N: is ``` 101174 ``` _//this is the answer that i want_

Answer (score 0):

From you current example it seems `FILTERXML()` would be best fit. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'P/N')]"),":","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

[image]

Comment: So the word after P/N: is ``` 101174 ``` _//this is the answer that i want_

Comment: @Biha See my edited formula.